# Equipment Suggestion Small Burette?

Tags: equipment

Is anyone familiar with a piece of equipment that can be purchased like a small burette? I need to find a way to dispense a liquid at a constant rate, however, the amount of liquid that I need to dispense will probably be less than 5 mL. A syringe is good in that regard, but it requires that I am able to push down with a constant pressure (which I doubt I can do). I've heard that they make burettes that are smaller (i.e around 25mL). Does anyone know if they make them smaller or at least not 2 feet long. Thank you for any useful information.

Comment: How about a syringe pump?

Comment: Yes, a syringe pump would work. I forgot to mention that the amount of money I can spend is around 50-75 dollars which is much less than most syringe pumps. Thank you for your response. We are considering trying to build a make-shift syringe pump but are still not sure if they could be something else we could purchase that'd be better/faster to get.

Comment: any old HPLC pump around?

Answer (score 4):

The usual commercially available burettes are standardizes in the international standard [ISO 385:2005 *Laboratory glassware – Burettes*](https://www.iso.org/standard/38678.html). This standard includes small burettes with capacities of 1, 2, 5, 10 and 25 ml. The very small versions are typically advertised as “micro burettes”.

$$
\begin{array}{lllll}
\hline
\text{Nominal capacity} & \text{Graduation divisions} & \text{Accuracy limits} & & \text{Max. length}\\
& & \text{Class A and AS} & \text{Class B} \\
\mathrm{ml} & \mathrm{ml} & \pm\ \mathrm{ml} & \pm\ \mathrm{ml} & \mathrm{mm}\\
\hline
1 & 0.01 & 0.006 & 0.01 & 575 \\
2 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 650 \\
5 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 820 \\
5 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 800 \\
10 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.05 & 820 \\
10 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 620 \\
25 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 820 \\
25 & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 620 \\
50 & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 820 \\
100 & 0.20 & 0.10 & 0.20 & 870 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Mflickin you can accept the answer...